# What's the meaning of "where" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

---

### "That's the one(=DVD) where this man, a car salesman, hires two criminals to kidnap his wife to get money from her rich father."

The above introduces the DVD 'Fargo'. What I couldn't understand is, the meaning of "where". What's the meaning of "where" here? 
Could you help me with that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the [definition of where](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/where) as a conjunction - the example phrase could alternatively be written:

> That's the one **in which** this man, a car salesman, hires two criminals to kidnap his wife to get money from her rich father."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's very helpful. So is that right that the below two sententences can make the above sentence?

Comment: 1. A carsales man hires two criminals to kidnap his wife so that he can get money from her rich father in the DVD.    2. That's the DVD.

Comment: 1+2 : That's the one(DVD) in which a car salesman hires two criminals to kidnap his wife so that he can get money from her rich father.

Comment: @Young Yes, you could look at it that way.